# adding cart items in session array to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

How can send the data from shopping cart into mysql database, at the moment i can add items into shopping cart and can clear however i have created checkout button as well but cant figure out on how to get the data from shopping cart to mysql database, i have tried the action check_out but am i doing this totaly wrong

this is my action.php which gets the items in shopping cart to array and adds or removes them.

```
<?php
include('cart/database_connection.php');
//action.php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    if($_POST["action"] == "add")
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
        {
            $is_available = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
            {
                if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"])
                {
                    $is_available++;
                    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] + $_POST["product_quantity"];
                }
            }
            if($is_available == 0)
            {
                $item_array = array(
                    'product_id'               =>     $_POST["product_id"],  
                    'product_name'             =>     $_POST["product_name"],  
                    'product_price'            =>     $_POST["product_price"],  
                    'product_quantity'         =>     $_POST["product_quantity"]
                );
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id'               =>     $_POST["product_id"],  
                'product_name'             =>     $_POST["product_name"],  
                'product_price'            =>     $_POST["product_price"],  
                'product_quantity'         =>     $_POST["product_quantity"]
            );
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
        }
    }

    if($_POST["action"] == 'remove')
    {
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
            if($values["product_id"] == $_POST["product_id"])
            {
                unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
            }
        }
    }
    if($_POST["action"] == 'empty')
    {
        unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
    }


    if($_POST["action"] == 'check_out')
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
        {
            foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $values)
        {
             $sql ="INSERT INTO orders (total, product_id)
                    values ('{$values['product_id']}','{$v['total']}')";
                    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                    $statement->execute();
        if ($statement) {
            $_SESSION['success'] = 'Information updated successfully';

            header("location: my_account.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['errormsg'] = 'Someting is wrong in updating your Information, Please try again later.';
            header("location: my_account2.php");
            exit;
        }}
    }

}
?>
```

and this is the script i am using the call the functions in my index.php

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_cart_data();

    function load_product()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"cart/fetch_item.php",
            method:"POST",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#display_item').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function load_cart_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"cart/fetch_cart.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#cart_details').html(data.cart_details);
                $('.total_price').text(data.total_price);
                $('.badge').text(data.total_item);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#cart-popover').popover({
        html : true,
        container: 'body',
        content:function(){
            return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.add_to_cart', function(){
        var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var product_name = $('#name'+product_id+'').val();
        var product_price = $('#price'+product_id+'').val();
        var product_quantity = $('#quantity'+product_id).val();
        var action = "add";
        if(product_quantity > 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"cart/action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price, product_quantity:product_quantity, action:action},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    load_cart_data();
                    alert("Item has been Added into Cart");
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please Enter Number of Quantity");
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
        var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var action = 'remove';
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this product?"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"cart/action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{product_id:product_id, action:action},
                success:function()
                {
                    load_cart_data();
                    $('#cart-popover').popover('hide');
                    alert("Item has been removed from Cart");
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#clear_cart', function(){
        var action = 'empty';
        $.ajax({
            url:"cart/action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action},
            success:function()
            {
                load_cart_data();
                $('#cart-popover').popover('hide');
                alert("Your Cart has been clear");
            }
        });
    });

$(document).on('click', '#check_out_cart', function(){
        var action = 'empty';
        $.ajax({
            url:"cart/action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action},
            success:function()
            {
                load_cart_data();
                $('#cart-popover').popover('hide');
                alert("Your Cart has been clear");
            }
        });
    });




});

</script>
```

databaseconnection.php

```
<?php

//database_connection.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foodsystem", "root", "");

?>
```

i have check the cart session and i can see the items in the array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [product_name] => Chicken Burger
            [product_price] => 10
            [product_quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [product_name] => Fish Burger
            [product_price] => 10
            [product_quantity] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [product_name] => Ham Burger
            [product_price] => 10
            [product_quantity] => 1
        )
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: Unless this is an academic project, remember that writing an ecommerce platform is an extraordinarily time-consuming undertaking and isn't a necessary exercise when there's many [existing platforms](https://magento.com) that can be adapted and extended for your needs, or frameworks that could dramatically simplify your build and help it conform to some kind of standard for organizing code.

Comment: though there many free software adaptives, but you must first understand how its made before updating any thing. i prefer creating my own, no matter the time.

Comment: @tadman it is academic project as long as its bit simple i got no problem but just stuck on this part

Comment: It's worth switching to the prepared statement model so you don't trip up over syntax errors. It also makes your queries easier for us to read and help you with. Are you sure the `$_SESSION` is set properly?

Comment: yeah the session should be set because i can get the items when i echo the session, i have updated it above it shows it @tadman

Answer (score 0):

You define a variable called `$sql` and you run one called `$query`.

These kinds of mistakes happen because queries as variables first and executing second is fundamentally problematic. It's much better to define the query as an argument so you can't "miss":

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (total, product_id) VALUES (:total, :product_id)");
$stmt->execute($v);
```

There is zero chance that runs the wrong query, or no query at all, by accident.

This also fixes the [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by using placeholder values, something that's so ridiculously easy with PDO that there's really no excuse to not do it. If you match up the named placeholders in the query with the keys in `$v` it will run with the right data automatically.